# How to prevent sprocket code clashes Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.1 is all nice and good, except with a fairly decent sized application I am getting lots of code clashes because rails is now throwing all my scripts together and serving them to every page. There must be a way to prevent page-specific code from being bundled up and served all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is `require_tree .` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Replace that line with one or more individual require statements.